# Can we prove we know all the ways to prove things?

Tags: logic

The things like induction and contradiction, they're all ways we prove things. Is that set of ways to prove things complete? Does the self referential nature of this question make it unprovable with something related to Gödel's incompleteness theorem? Has it been proven to be unprovable if this is the case? Is there some proof that shows we have found all the ways to prove things?

Comment: No way to answer without defining rigorously something... For [first-order logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic) we have the [Completeness theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Completeness_and_undecidability) showing the "adequacy" of the logical tools for the task. But not every "mathematical fact" can be expressed using FOL.

Comment: Exactly, peano arithmetic is not complete but propositional calculus is.

Comment: [Second- and Higher-order logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-order_logic#Deductive_systems) is more "expressive", but in this case we loose the completeness of the deductive system.

Comment: And we have [Gödel’s Incompleteness Theorems](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/goedel-incompleteness/) showing that a single "manageable" formal theory cannot be enough to prove every sentence implied by the axioms of the theory, that means (in rough terms) that we have to "add resources" (logical and intellectual) to find proof not available in the theory.

Comment: if there's no way to answer without defining the system, does that mean some systems we can prove we have a complete set of tools to prove things and some we can't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't and we can't. Ways of proving things are just axioms. According to the Gödel's First Incompleteness Theorem, if your axiomatic system includes Peano Arithmetic, there are true statements that you can't prove, moreover, if you add more axioms (or proving ways), there will be other true statements that are unprovable.

Comment: So when we prove things we're proving them within an axiomatic system defined by the axioms which we then use to prove things in that system? If the system is defined by its axioms doesn't that imply that for that system we can only use the axioms that define it? Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Yes, we are using the axioms of the axiomatic system that we are working on.

Comment: Oops, you are right

Answer (score 3):

I feel it is important to clarify some definitions, because there are two distinct notions of completeness: semantic completeness and syntactic completeness. **The answer is yes with respect to semantic completeness, but no with respect to syntactic completeness.** It seems to me what you are after is semantic completeness.

In what follows, we suppose that we have specified a logical (deductive) system, and a theory in this logical system. For example, take first order logic with ZFC set theory, or first order logic with group theory.

**Semantic completeness**

A statement $\phi$ in the theory is *provable* if one can derive it from the rules of the deductive system.

Now for each theory there is the notion of a *model* of that theory, and given a specific model we can ask whether a statement is satisfied in this model. I won't attempt to define this, but here are some examples: a group is a model for the theory of groups, the set of natural numbers is a model for Peano arithmetic, a set-theoretic universe is a model for set theory. So we define a statement to be valid in a theory if it is satisfied in every model of the theory.

Two reasonable questions we could ask about our system are

1. Soundness: Does provability entail validity?
2. (*Semantic*) completeness: Does validity entail provability?

In general we always ask that our system is sound. For completeness, [Gödel's *completeness* theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_completeness_theorem) tells us that any theory over first order logic is complete in this sense. For example, the statement $\phi := \forall x,y. (x*y)^{-1} = y^{-1}*x^{-1}$ is something that is true in *every* group, and indeed, it is easily derivable from the axioms of group theory. This form of completeness also holds for ZFC set theory.

**Syntactic completeness**

However there is yet another notion of completeness. A theory is (*syntactically*) complete if for any statement $\phi$, we can either derive $\phi$ or $\neg\phi$ in our system. Now we know that $\phi$ can only be derivable if it is satisfied in every model of our theory, and similarly for $\neg \phi$.

An interesting question is therefore whether our theory has a statement $\phi$ which is satisfied in some model $M$, and its negation $\neg\phi$ is satisfied in another model $N$. If this is the case, then we can deduce that neither $\phi$ nor $\neg \phi$ is derivable in our system (*note:* this says nothing about the derivability of $\phi\vee\neg\phi$)! For the theory of groups, the statement $\forall x,y. x* y = y * x$ is such a statement, because some groups are abelian and others are not.

Now [Gödel's *incompleteness* theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_incompleteness_theorems) tells us that any theory which is strong enough to do arithmetic is incomplete in this way. In fact, there are numerous axioms of set theory which hold in some models of set theory but not others, such as the axiom of choice or the continuum hypothesis, meaning that they are independent of the theory.